# Get a node's index

Tags: javascript

Given any arbitrary node in the DOM, is it possible to get the Node's index so that I can use it in nth-child?  I have tried the following without success

```
function getNodeIndex(node){
    if(undefined == node){return undefined;}
    if(undefined == node.parentNode){return undefined;}
    if(undefined == node.parentNode.childNodes){return undefined;}
    for (var i=0;i<node.parentNode.childNodes.length;i++){
        if(node.parentNode.childNodes[i]==node){return i;}
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function seems to return some strange results, mostly because it also counts textNodes, comments and everything else, not just the elements.

I'd do it like this, counting up through sibling elements and making it zero based

```
function getNodeIndex(elem) {
    if (elem && elem.parentNode) {
        var i = 0;
        while( elem.previousElementSibling ) {
            i++;
            elem = elem.previousElementSibling;
        }
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```